# Exporting PS Members from Module Fails

Tags: powershell

I have a psm1 module with several functions. I only want to expose some of the functions, so I used "Export-ModuleMember -Function " and everything was fine.

Now I want to add a manifest, so I removed the Export-ModuleMember cmdlet and put the function names under the FunctionsToExport section of the psd1 file.

When I import the module, I can tab-complete the functions, but when I try to use them, ps says:

> Test-Function : The term 'Test-Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I also tried putting Export-ModuleMember -Function * into the psm1, but that didn't help.

The psm1 and psd1 files are named the same and are in the root of the module.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: It's not caching as suggested. This is the expected behavior. This is actually a duplicate question but I'm on mobile and can't find the dup target right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I had forgotten to un-comment the RooteModule node. Once I did that (and had module.psm1 as the value), the exported commands showed up in the "Get-Module module" output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that PowerShell caching mechanism is involved here. Try to run:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Refresh
```

I recommend [very good article on that subject](http://www.powertheshell.com/how-module-command-discovery-works-in-psv3/) written by PowerShell MVP Tobias Weltner.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with caching. With the manifest file in place, Get-Module (after tab-completion of a function) shows the type as Manifest and there are no exported commands. If I delete the manifest file and remove/import the module again, I see the type is Script and I have all of the functions in the list of exported commands (because I have Export-ModuleMember -Function * in the psm1).

Comment: I should add that the manifest file has "FunctionsToExport = 'Test-Function', 'Test-Function2'"